# How can I delete a particular mysql entry?

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row, corresponding-records

In the project that I am working on, a user has a list of entries that have been made which are stored on a mysql database. Here I display all of the entries, or `ideas` that I user has made by displaying all of the entries that match their username.

I want to have a delete button next to each entry that deletes **only** that entry when it is pressed. With the code below, all of the entries seem to be deleted immediately no matter if the delete button has been pressed or not.

```
<?php
$username = $_SESSION['Username'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ideas` WHERE Username = '$username' ORDER BY `ideaID`") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>

<?php $id_num = $row[0] ?>
<b>Title: </b> <?= $row[2]?><br><b>Description: </b> <?= $row[3]?> <br>
<a onclick ="<?php mysql_query("DELETE FROM `ideas` WHERE ideaId = '$id_num'");?>">
<div id="deleteButton">delete</div></a>
<br><br>


<?php } ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING** your code is susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Try replacing $id_num in the anchor tag by $row[0]

Comment: @AmitBhargava His approach is wrong, so that's not the place to start. Additionally, he's defining `$id_num` as `$row[0]`. Your suggestion would make no change at all.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how PHP works. All the PHP code is being executed once your file is run, and that includes your `mysql_query` that deletes. It doesn't matter if you write `<a onclick=` or whatever you do, that's HTML, and just nonsense to PHP. PHP just outputs it without further ado.

What you want is replace the link with a form that submits the ID you wish to another PHP page that then executes the delete MySQL query. This link could also be made with an AJAX request that happened in the background. Alternatively, you could just use a link to accomplish the same thing, but this is considered bad style.

As a little exercise to help you understand why this doesn't work, take a look at the source code it generates. It'll just be an empty `<a onclick="">`. If PHP was to work as you expect, what should be written there?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
              <?php mysql_query("DELETE FROM `ideas` WHERE ideaId = '$id_num'");
```

When it goes through loop mysql_query executes DELETE query for each item and that is why it gets deleted. You need to simply generate a link that points to delete.php and passes record id as an argument and then have mysql_query("DELETE code in delete.php page

Comment: How might I generate this link?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a separate request from the client back to the server using AJAX or a complete postback.